# Is it possible to force Grails/Gorm to not include a column in an insert?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For instance, suppose I wanted to let that column be set to whatever the database defaults it to, without redefining that default in the domain class?

I can't find much through Google. There are hints that if I were working with Hibernate directly, I could set that particular column/property to private, and this might accomplish what I seek.

I can of course leave that column undefined, and GORM ignores it. But I need the values out of it whenever the Grails app does a select.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason you don't want the DB default to also be set in the domain class as that field's default?

Comment: Because I have hundreds of legacy tables, and it's a pain defining them in a domain class as it is. Additionally, I'm trying to use the oracle rowid... which is fine. Until I go to try to save the model, then it bitches that I'm leaving that property unset or if I allow it to be nullable then it gripes *ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification*. I'd like to be able to read rowid from the model, but I don't want it to ever try to set it.

Comment: http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Read-Only-columns-td1390025.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GORM property insertable as in [doc](http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/insertable.html) or can read the value with a `beforeInsert` event:

```
class Book {
    String title
    String isbn

    static mapping = {
        isbn nullable: false
    }

    def beforeInsert {
        title = queryFromDatabase...
    }
}
```

Comment: If I do this, then I get a "Field error in object X on field Y: rejected value [null]". If I set it to nullable true (along with insertable false), then it gives me the "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification" error. And of course nullable true by itself fails with the same.

Comment: This is on Grails 2.0.4 btw, and I checked to make sure insertable wasn't something only in 2.1+  I've done a clean, I restarted the debugger... I'm screwing something up, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: Ummm...ok, what about to read the value from the db before     insert using  def beforeInsert() {
        title = queryFromDatabase...
    }

Comment: Nevermind. I was putting that in constraints and not mapping. I'm accepting your answer. For the record I would have accepted it from cdeszaq if he had made it an answer and not a comment, since he was first...

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, the link you provided is the true answer: http://grails.org/doc/2.1.0/ref/Database%20Mapping/insertable.html, using `insertable` and `updateable` both equal to `false`, worked nicely, thx.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go the beforeInsert / Hibernate interceptor route since your requirement is to read default values from an existing database.

You can read the database default values for columns with JDBC's [DatabaseMetaData.getColumns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) .

To find out the database table and column names, you can use something like this (this code is not tested)

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.Mapping
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DomainClassArtefactHandler

def gdc=grailsApplication.getArtefact(DomainClassArtefactHandler.TYPE, someInstance.class.name)
Mapping mapping=GrailsDomainBinder.getMapping(gdc)
def tableName=mapping.tableName
def columnName=mapping.getPropertyConfig('someColumn').column
```

This is not a complete answer, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Every answer helps. Thank you. I'm like a chimp with a rock banging on a tv trying to fix it, when it comes to Grails.